# Why is Linear Programming is called 'programming' instead of 'optimization'?

Tags: optimization, terminology, linear-programming, math-history, quadratic-programming

In numerical optimization (a mathematics branch), a standard `optimization` problem is formulated as:
$$\min\quad f(x)$$
$$\text{subject to, }\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$c(x) = 0\text{ or }c(x) ≥ 0$$

But when these functions are all linear/quadratic, the `optimization` terminology is changed to `linear/quadratic programming`.

So I have the following questions:

1. What is the difference between `optimization` and `programming`?
2. Why has this terminology changed?

Comment: Question 1 belongs to a specialist domain better answered by domain experts. In doing so, they might answer Question 2. On its own, Q2 might go on [hsm.se].

Comment: Thanks Andrew for this kind action. But actually,I first post this question in mathematics exchange, and then it was closed. So I went to the English stack exchange.

Comment: The question does not relate to the nuts and bolts of English, but specific terms of art and their history. And the two upvotes were both made here after migration.

Comment: This question already exists on MO, and has some good answers there: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145077/why-are-optimization-problems-often-called-programs

Comment: Thanks for this post. From that post, we know the origin of the name `programming` coming from Dantzig. But what remains is why and when was this terminology changed to `optimization`?

Comment: Short answer: blame the military.